# Get LINQ class item properties from GridView SelectedItem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a LinqDataSource that feeds data to GridView in ASP Web Form. However, in my GridView I'm not showing all columns of my SQL table (thus my LINQ class). Now I want to get the primary key value (let's call it RecordID) from my GridView.SelectedItem. How do I access my LINQ class object bound to SelectedItem so I could then access that object's properties?

Comment: I usually don't use a LinqDataSource. I create a method that either calls the Stored Procedure or Table via linq, and then bind it to a control. This allows me to do what you want to the List or IEnumerable objects before binding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `datakeynames` attribute of gridview as below:

```
 <asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
    datasourceid="CustomersSource" 
    autogeneratecolumns="true"
    emptydatatext="No data available." 
    autogenerateselectbutton="true"    
    datakeynames="CustomerID"
    onselectedindexchanged="CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
    runat="server">

  </asp:gridview>
```

Then in code behind datakey(s) of selected row can be accessed as below:

```
void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   // Determine the index of the selected row.
   int index = CustomersGridView.SelectedIndex;

   // Display the primary key value of the selected row.
   Message.Text = "The primary key value of the selected row is " +
   CustomersGridView.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString() + ".";

}
```

Comment: PaulThere is no Value property to members of this array.